# Mix numbered/unnumbered sections/subsections

Tags: sectioning, numbering, sections-paragraphs, amsart

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}

\title{Title 1}
\maketitle

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Sub-section 1}
Text 1

\section{Section 2}
\subsection{Sub-section 2}
Text 2

\section*{Unnumbered section}
\subsection{Numbered sub-section}
Text 3

\section{Section 4}
\subsection{Sub-section 4}
Text 4

\section*{Unnumbered section}
\subsection{Numbered sub-section}
Text 5

\section{Section 6}
\subsection{Sub-section 6}
Text 6

\end{document}
```

You see how with the unnumbered sections, the sub-sections of the unnumbered sections are not correct since it continues from the previous section's sub-section, which is unwanted behavior. For example, for the "Text 3" sub-section, it should be sub-section 3.1, not 2.2. Also the next section is numbered as section 3 when it should be section 4, and so forth.

Comment: Why do you expect that unnumbered section etc. should restart the subsection etc. numbers? That's not the case in a normal setup. A manual solution for each `\section*` would be `\stepcounter{section}`  -- a unnumbered structure command does not increase its counter -- this is the design of LaTeX -- Mixing the styles seems wrong!

Comment: you can try with `{\def\thesection{}
\section{Unnumbered section}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following patch (thanks to [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)) updates one of the sectional internals - `\@sect` - to always step the counter in question, regardless of whether you use `\section*` or `\section`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\@sect}{\@svsec\@empty}{\@svsec\@empty\stepcounter{#1}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{Title 1}
\maketitle

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Sub-section 1}
Text 1

\section{Section 2}
\subsection{Sub-section 2}
Text 2

\section*{Unnumbered section}
\subsection{Numbered sub-section}
Text 3

\section{Section 4}
\subsection{Sub-section 4}
Text 4

\section*{Unnumbered section}
\subsection{Numbered sub-section}
Text 5

\section{Section 6}
\subsection{Sub-section 6}
Text 6

\end{document}
```